# Firebase: Retrieving as Object/Model. Coming from Java

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

So far I have developed android apps with java and Firebase. Now I want to code my first iOS app with Firebase as well. I have this Database Model:

[image]

I want to retrieve these Objects and store them in an array. My ExercisePresets Model looks like this:

```
class ExercisePreset {
var key : String?
var name : String?
var type : String = "Dynamic";
var progressions : [String] = [String]();

//@Exclude
var selected : Bool = false;

init() { }

convenience init(name : String, type : String) {
    self.init();
    self.name = name;
    self.type = type;
}
```

}

In Java I could just get the snapshot as an Object of my Model like this:

```
fb.getRefUserPresets(null).addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            ExcersisePresets e = dataSnapshot.getValue(ExcersisePresets.class);
            e.setKey(dataSnapshot.getKey());
            presets.add(e);
        }
}
```

but I don't get how this works for swift. I tried this:

```
refPresets!.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

        let e = snapshot.value as! ExercisePreset;
    }
```

But I get this error:

```
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x109d594f8) to 'TrainingsLog.ExercisePreset' (0x106a30408).
```

So how do I retrieve my Objects the right way?

Comment: FYI - You don't need semicolons in Swift.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to cast it as `NSDictionary`

```
refPresets!.observe(.childAdded) { (snapshot) in

    let e = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary

   print(e)
}
```

Comment: This is Swift. Cast it to a Swift dictionary, not NSDictionary.

Comment: I have already did that but this way I still don't have an Object of type ExercisePreset...

Comment: the return can't be used directly you have to parse the dictionary items and initialize ExercisePreset with the values

Answer (score 0):

You have to cast your snapshot.value as NSDictionary

Comment: No, this is Swift. Cast it to a Swift dictionary, not NSDictionary.

Comment: But how do I get an "ExercisePreset" Object that way?

Comment: You can make a init that takes a Dictionary as parameter and initialize your object. Or you can extract a value from each line of dictionary and init your object one by one parameter.